# C# Managed EWS get email By ID from shared mailbox

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS to manage emails of a shared mailbox through a console application.

Once they have been processed they are moved to another folder under the shared inbox (after saving the message id to a SQL record).

Through a separate process I want to retrieve the email using the ID.

When use the code:

```
var email = EmailMessage.Bind(serviceInstance, new ItemId(id));
```

The service throws this exception:

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: 'The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.'

I know that the service user has permissions on the inbox and folder as the same service has previously read the inbox and moved the email.

Answer (score 1):

**The reason** according to the MS [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-move-and-copy-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange) is:

> when you move or copy an email message into a different folder, a
>   new item is created in the new folder with a unique item ID, and the
>   original message is deleted.

Therefore you get the exception: `The specified object was not found in the store.`

**How to work around it?**

Before processing an email messasge, [create a custom extended property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633654(v=exchg.80)) and set it on the email message and save the email message, to share the new state with the EWS server.

```
Guid myPropertySetId = new Guid("{20B5C09F-7CAD-44c6-BDBF-8FCBEEA08544}"); 
ExtendedPropertyDefinition myExtendedPropertyDefinition = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(myPropertySetId, "MyExtendedPropertyName", MapiPropertyType.String); 
message.SetExtendedProperty(myExtendedPropertyDefinition, "MyExtendedPropertyValueIdentifingAnEmailMessageToBeMoved");
message.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Store the value of the `myExtendedPropertyDefinition` (in the above example:  `"MyExtendedPropertyValueIdentifingAnEmailMessageToBeMoved"`) before you move the email message. Then you can move the email message to its destination folder.

After the original email has been processed (moved > deleted), you can [find the email message at its new destination](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2010/02/25/determining-the-id-of-a-sent-message-by-using-extended-properties-with-the-ews-managed-api/) by seaching for the custom property and the value you stored to identify the email message:

```
ItemView view = new ItemView(5); 
SearchFilter searchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(myExtendedPropertyDefinition, "MyExtendedPropertyValueIdentifingAnEmailMessageToBeMoved"); 
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Subject, myExtendedPropertyDefinition); 
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, searchFilter, view);
```

Use for every email message a unique identifying value in order to get one search result.

Please note that this work around is the officially (by MS) suggested approach as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-move-and-copy-email-messages-by-using-ews-in-exchange).